# Android 4.0 org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to ... timed out

Tags: android, timeout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am facing a weird problem since I test my applications on ICS.

Using the following code on Android 2.X works well (sometimes timeouts happen but very few times) :

```
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

    final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        if (keys != null) {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
        }

        // Cookies
        // Create a local instance of cookie store
        if (checkCookieValues()) {
            BasicClientCookie cookieSession = new BasicClientCookie(mCookieName, mCookieValue);
            cookieSession.setDomain(mCookieDomain);
            httpClient.getCookieStore().clear();
            httpClient.getCookieStore().addCookie(cookieSession);
        }

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error when calling postData", e);
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error when calling postData", e);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error when calling postData", e);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error when calling postData", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error when calling postData", e);
    }

    return response;
```

On ICS, as soon as I receive a time out exception, all next calls will return a timeout exception.

```
    Timeout exception received :
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /78.109.91.193:80 timed out
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at com.kreactive.planningtv.service.PlanningTVService.postData(PlanningTVService.java:1554)
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at com.kreactive.planningtv.service.PlanningTVService.fbConnect(PlanningTVService.java:1897)
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at com.kreactive.planningtv.service.PlanningTVService.onHandleIntent(PlanningTVService.java:569)
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-06 19:06:05.425: E/PLTV:PlanningTVService(2980):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Does anyone faced the problem ? Is there a way to avoid this problem ?
I checked and didn't find a similar question (for ICS especially).

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: can you get any solution for this

Comment: Did you run this code in a unique thread?

Comment: I have similar code on a background thread and notice the same issue whenever changing my target to 4.X. ConnectTimeoutExceptions are thrown randomly, but often. This was not a problem when targetting 2.X

Answer (score -2):

Within an Android application you should avoid performing long running operations on the user interface thread. This includes file and network access.

**StrictMode** allows to setup policies in your application to avoid doing incorrect things. As of **Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) StrictMode is configured to crash with a NetworkOnMainThreadException exception, if network is accessed in the user interface thread**.

While you should do network access in a background thread.

If you are targeting Android 3.0 or higher, you can turn this check off via the following code at the beginning of your onCreate() method of your activity.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

It is not advised to turn this off.

Comment: who soever gave down vote, can you please mention reason here.

Answer (score -3):

The Apache http stack is deprecated and broken in ICS. Chromium is now the standard. Ensure that v8 is your devices default java script engine.

Comment: I don't think this is related. Check the like above to have a possible answer we are going to test soon. Anyway, thank you for your answer.